# Environment variables names are not replaced with values in airflow DAG

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to execute a SQL code in my airflow dag. Which I can achieve.
I have to put environment variable names in my SQL code and during execution of DAG, the name of variable should be replaced with value of variable.

**tryMyDag.py**

```
projectId = "`" + os.environ["GCP_PROJECT_ENV"]

stockLevels = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='trafficSignals',
      use_legacy_sql=False,
      sql='/dags/sqls/trafficSignals_v1.sql',
```

**trafficSignals.sql**

```
select * from  projectId.dataset_name.trafficSignals_vw`
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Renato. I used the user defined macros and resolved this issue. But there are multiple ways are there to solve this. I found it. Airflow variables can be defined in .py and use it in .sql as `{{var.value.projectId}}`. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an environment variable inside the sql file? If so, I think it is not possible, however you can use a python file with the SQL code, just replace you `dags/sqls/trafficSignals_v1.sql` to a `dags/sqls/traffic_signals_v1.py`, and inside it put a variable:

```
select_trafficSignals = """
select * from  projectId.dataset_name.trafficSignals_vw
...
{place you need a os env}
""".format(os.environ['...'])
```

Then in `tryMyDag.py` refer to this text variable:

```py
from sqls.traffic_signals_v1 import select_trafficSignals

stockLevels = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='trafficSignals',
      use_legacy_sql=False,
      sql=select_trafficSignals,
```